# Using 2 different convertvers

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Trying to use 2 different converters and it seems even though I specify 1 converter it is being passed to another.

In my UserControl.Resources I have the following

```
<local:AlertIDToImageConverter x:Key="AlertIDToImageConverter" />
<local:AlertIDToImageConverter x:Key="IsNewToImageConverter" />
```

In my DataTemplate I have the following

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=IsNew, Converter={StaticResource IsNewToImageConverter}}" Width="12" Height="12" />
<Image Source="{Binding Path=AlertID, Converter={StaticResource AlertIDToImageConverter}}" Width="12" Height="12" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0" />
```

IsNew which is a bool is being passed to the AlertID converter which is an int and fails.

What I'm I not understanding correctly about how the converters should work?

Comment: plz post converter codes.

Comment: It's been fix. Was my fault using copy/paste and forgetting to rename.

Comment: with a bool value which can be only `true` or `false` it is probably simpler to use DataTrigger, unless that logic is used in many places

Comment: @ASh the only additional code used in the bool converter is that it takes a resource icon and converts it to an ImageSource using an extension method. Could that still be done in a DataTrigger?

Comment: @Tsukasa, I didn't understand part about "take a resource icon and convert it to an ImageSource using an extension method" :). but nevermind

Comment: @ASh I have .ico's as resources. In the IsNew converter, it takes the Icon and converts it into an ImageSource.

Comment: @Tsukasa, it can be `<Image Source="../Resources/NewItem.ico"`. or with a Setter : `<Setter Property="Source" Value="../Resources/NewItem.ico"/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess, but

```
<local:AlertIDToImageConverter x:Key="IsNewToImageConverter" />
```

should probably be

```
<local:IsNewToImageConverter x:Key="IsNewToImageConverter" />
```

Comment: haha wow copy and paste fail. Thanks.